# How to add vbs to paste as values?

Tags: vba, paste

i cant seem to get my code to paste as values, it keeps bugging out when i try changing paste to paste values

original code

```
Sub copyData()




Sheets("Master - DO NOT TOUCH").Select
LR = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("C8:T" & LR).copy
Sheets("Customs Master Sheet").Select
Range("C8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("C:T").AutoFit






End Sub
```

ive tried to do this

```
Sub copyData()




Sheets("Master - DO NOT TOUCH").Select
LR = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("C8:T" & LR).copy
Sheets("Customs Master Sheet").Select
Range("C8").Select.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Columns("C:T").AutoFit






End Sub
```

but the yellow debug appears from "Range..." row

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok i  managed to figure it out it works now :D

```
Sub copyData()




Sheets("Master - DO NOT TOUCH").Select
LR = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("C8:T" & LR).copy
Sheets("Customs Master Sheet").Select


Range("C8").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Columns("C:T").AutoFit






End Sub
```